# HoltWinters function works fine when used by itself with purrr:map but not when used in an ifelse function

Tags: r, time-series, purrr, holtwinters

I am trying to use a `HoltWinters` prediction iteratively along a vector, without the use of a loop, but don't want the `HoltWinters` function used on the first two. I have created a list of vectors using `accumulate`:

```
library(purrr)

v <- c(73,77,71,73,86,87,90)
cumv <- accumulate(v,c)
```

Using `map` across `cumv`:

```
# Omit first two 
hw1 <- map(cumv[-c(1:2)], function(x) HoltWinters(ts(x),gamma=F,alpha=0.35,beta=0.2))

> hw1[[5]]

#Holt-Winters exponential smoothing with trend and without seasonal component.

#Call:
#HoltWinters(x = ts(x), alpha = 0.35, beta = 0.2, gamma = F)

#Smoothing parameters:
# alpha: 0.35
# beta : 0.2
# gamma: FALSE

#Coefficients:
#       [,1]
#a 89.605082
#b  3.246215
```

This
gives my desired result but doesn't include the first two iterations. I assumed using `ifelse` would work fine:

```
# Include first two, use ifelse
hw2 <- map(cumv, function(x) ifelse(length(x)>2,HoltWinters(ts(x),gamma=F,alpha=0.35,beta=0.2),
                                    ifelse(length(x)>1,max(x),NA)))
```

Now, `hw2[[7]]` should have (I thought) returned an identical object to `hw1[[5]]` but it doesn't.

```
> hw2[[7]]

#[[1]]
#Time Series:
#Start = 3 
#End = 7 
#Frequency = 1 
#      xhat    level    trend
#3 81.00000 77.00000 4.000000
#4 80.80000 77.50000 3.300000
#5 80.82400 78.07000 2.754000
#6 85.75192 82.63560 3.116320
#7 89.39243 86.18875 3.203686
```

Why is it getting messed up?

Comment: `ifelse` doesn't quite do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dason mentioned in their comment, the `ifelse()` function is not the same as using `if else` statements. The former returns a single value for each element of x, assuming x is a vector containing booleans, e.g.

```
x <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
ifelse (x, "A", "B")
```

returns `[1] "A" "A" "B" "B"`

For your purpose, you want to use a normal `if else` construct:

```
hw2 <- map(cumv, function(x) {
    if (length(x) > 2) {
        return (HoltWinters(ts(x),gamma=F,alpha=0.35,beta=0.2))
    } else if (length(x) > 1) {
        return (max(x))
    } else {
        return (NA)
    }
})
```

Comment: Got it - I also realised theres a workaround using `map_if`. Thanks